# How to show all child records from JSON results not just last record

Tags: php, javascript, json, dojo

Currently I have a many to one relationships and I need my map viewer to show all the child records not just the last record.  I have researched and found that possibly I could be rewriting the variable over again which is why the last record is the only one that shows.  I did test to make sure all records were in fact coming through using fiddler.  Please help.

See PHP code below

```
 <?php error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
 $pole = $_GET["pole"];


 // Connect to SQL Server database
 include("../connections/PubgisConnect.php");

// Construct query
$tsql = "Select [dbo].[TRANS_POLE].[PoleID], [dbo].[TRANS_POLE].[PoleType], [dbo]. 
FROM [pubgis].[dbo].[TRANS_POLE]
INNER JOIN [pubgis].[dbo].[TRANS_SIGN] ON [pubgis].[dbo].[TRANS_POLE].[PoleID][pubgis]     [dbo].[TRANS_SIGN].PoleID INNER JOIN [pubgis].[dbo].[TRANS_SIGNINSPECTION] ON [pubgis].[dbo].[TRANS_SIGN].SignID = [pubgis].[dbo].[TRANS_SIGNINSPECTION].SignID
WHERE [pubgis].[dbo].[TRANS_POLE].[PoleID] = '$pole'";


// Execute query
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);
if( $stmt === false )
  {
    echo "Error in executing query.</br>";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
  }
$results = array();
// Retrieve and display the results of the query 
$lastFeatType = "";
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    array_push($results,$row);
  }

  echo json_encode($results);

 // Free statement and connection resources
 sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
 sqlsrv_close( $conn);
 ?>
```

Code below is from my index file

```
dojo.xhrGet({
        url: "StreetSignsProfile.php",
        handleAs: "json",
        content:{pole: pole},
        load: function(data) {
            for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
                var obj = data[i];
                var pole = obj["PoleID"];
                var encodedPole = encodeURIComponent(pole);
        var na = "<span class='notAvail'>not available</span >";
                dojo.byId("idHeader").innerHTML = obj["PoleID"];
                dojo.byId("PoleType").innerHTML = obj["PoleType"];

                //Sign Code
                dojo.byId("SignID").innerHTML = obj["SignID"];
                dojo.byId("SignCode").innerHTML = obj["SignCode"];.
```

View above results
                            
                
                    
                        
                            Pole Information
                            
                    Pole Type

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Do not use this code until you've learned about them and plugged the holes.

Comment: @MarcB Do you have any suggestions about dynamically creating the tables or avoiding rewriting the variable?